# iCloud Calendar sync in application

Tags: calendar, icloud, icalendar, caldav, icloud-api

I am creating application as like [Sunrise](https://calendar.sunrise.am/), [Calendar by Riddle](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/calendars-by-readdle-sync/id608834326?mt=8), [Tiny Calendar](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tiny-calendar-sync-google/id514917848?mt=8), [Calendar 5](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/calendars-5-event-task-manager/id697927927?mt=8).

Requirement is to add multiple iCloud Calendar in application as like above applications doing.

I want to sync Apple Calendar (iCal) as like this applications. I got success with Google Calendar Sync, but not finding way to sync iCal. Don't know how this all applications are accomplishing it. Whether they are doing from App side or from server side?

I have go through [CalDAV](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/caldav/v2/guide), but not finding way.

Any one have idea from which API I can implement iCloud Calendar sync in my application?

If any one have ever implemented multiple iCloud Calendar Sync then please help me.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your question is. Why didn't CalDAV work for you? What about EventKit, that doesn't do a lot, but maybe it is sufficient for you?

Comment: @hnh: EventKit only fetch events from iCloud account linked with our device, but I want to login multiple iCloud account within application.So if you have any idea then please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

iCloud currently uses [CalDAV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791) to community with the Calendar apps on iOS and macOS. You can easily look at the CalDAV requests/responses exchanged between those and iCloud using a tool like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com).

This is a pretty good introduction on how to build a CalDAV client:
[Building a CalDAV client](http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/).

You may want to come back with more specific questions if you run into issues. "I have go through CalDAV, but not finding way." is a little, well, very vague ;-)